# copy from t1 into new table t2 filtering out duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1136

I have a table `t1`, some rows have duplicates in all columns EXCEPT `id`. 
`t1`'s `id` is AUTO_INCREMENT and has 1MIL rows.
`t2` is a new table without data and the `id` does not need AUTO_INCREMENT as i will probably create a new column for this.

**Q:** After i create `t2`, how can i copy from `t1` into `t2` where distinct values from `t1` in all columns, so that `t2` has no duplicate rows

I am on amazons `RDS`  `ENGINE=InnoDB`

t1 - this is what i have

```
+---+-----+-----+------+-------+
|id |fname|lname|mytext|morevar|
|---|-----|-----|------|-------|
| 1 | joe | min | abc  | 123   |
| 2 | joe | min | abc  | 123   |
| 3 | mar | kam | def  | 789   |
| 4 | kel | smi | ghi  | 456   |
+------------------------------+
```

t2 - this is what i would like to end up with

```
+---+-----+-----+------+-------+
|id |fname|lname|mytext|morevar|
|---|-----|-----|------|-------|
| 1 | joe | min | abc  | 123   |
| 3 | mar | kam | def  | 789   |
| 4 | kel | smi | ghi  | 456   |
+------------------------------+
```

this is my attempt, but got: `Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

```
INSERT INTO t2 (id,fname,lname,mytext,morevar)
SELECT DISTINCT st.mytext
FROM t1 st
 WHERE st.id>0 
 AND st.id<=1000
```

Comment: Your example `t1` shows not only duplicate data in `mytext`, but also in all other columns (except `id`).  If the data differed, which record should be preserved (and which dropped)?

Comment: @eggyal im not sure where you are seeing duplicates?  `t2` is what i would like to end up with, it does not contain data

Comment: No, but `t1` contains a duplicate and it's not clear why you chose record 1 over record 2.  Indeed, had their values been different in other columns (but the same in `mytext`), might you have instead chosen record 2 over record 1?

Comment: Oh i see what you mean, i wasnt clear on choosing the lower id number

Comment: In that case, I concur with [@Gordon Linoff's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17583434).

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use `group by`:

```
INSERT INTO t2 (id,fname,lname,mytext,morevar)
    SELECT id,fname,lname,mytext,morevar
    FROM t1 st
    WHERE st.id>0 AND st.id<=1000 
    group by mytext;
```

However, technically, this is not correct because the column values are not guaranteed to come from the same row.  So, the right way is:

```
INSERT INTO t2 (id,fname,lname,mytext,morevar)
    SELECT st.id, st.fname, st.lname, st.mytext, st.morevar
    FROM t1 st join
         (select mytext, min(id) as minid
          from t1
          group by mytext
         ) mint
         on st.id = minid
    WHERE st.id>0 AND st.id<=1000 ;
```

Comment: since i have 1MIL rows, how big of chunks do you recommend i set the 'where' clause?  1 thousand rows at a time? 10K rows? 100K rows?

Comment: @tq . . . I don't generally batch inserts.  The cost in this query is going to be the aggregation on `mytext`, not the insert portion.

Comment: its been over 10 minutes to do a batch of 1000 and the process is still going? do you think there is an issue with this? does it normally take this long?

Comment: are you saying that `WHERE st.id>0 AND st.id<=1000` does not stop at 1000?  in other words this will go through the entire 1MIL rows?

Comment: @tq . . . The issue is almost certainly the aggregation on the text field and not the insert.  You can try that out by running it separately or doing a `create temporary table`.  I'll have to think a bit harder about the solution to the performance problem.  However, you might want to create an index on `(mytext, id)` before running the query.

Comment: Thank you for all this help.  so if i take off `WHERE st.id>0 AND st.id<=1000`,  then how do i add an index on `mytext,id` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `GROUP BY` to make just that column distinct.

```
INSERT INTO t2 (id,fname,lname,mytext,morevar)
SELECT id, fname, lname, mytext, morevar
FROM t1 st
 WHERE st.id>0 
 AND st.id<=1000 
GROUP BY mytext
```

If the other columns differ between the duplicates, it will pick values from them arbitrarily (not necessarily from the same rows, even).

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, it will select the smallest id number of duplicates and takes into account all columns.

```
INSERT INTO t2 (id,fname,lname,mytext,morevar)
SELECT min(id) id, fname, lname, mytext, morevar
FROM t1
WHERE t1.id > 0 and t1.id <= 1000
GROUP BY fname, lname, mytext, morevar
ORDER BY id;
```